# Working on overloaded package throws "Failed to resolve object details"

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, package

I am working on an overloaded package and was wondering 2 things.

1) Is there a way to get more info on what error occurred, like what line number it occurred on, as `Failed to resolve object details` seams a bit vague.

2) What appears to be wrong with this statement?

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE shop_query_pkg IS
     procedure shop_info 
      (p_id IN bb_shopper.idshopper%TYPE,
       p_firstname out bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE);
      procedure shop_info 
      (p_id IN bb_shopper.lastname%TYPE,
       p_firstname out bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE);
    END;
    /
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY show_query_pkg IS
     procedure shop_info 
      (p_id IN bb_shopper.idshopper%TYPE,
       p_firstname out bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE);
      IS
     BEGIN
       SELECT firstname
        into p_firstname
        FROM bb_shopper
        WHERE idshopper = p_id;
     EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID does not exist');
     END;
     -- second procedure
     procedure shop_info 
      (p_id IN bb_shopper.lastname%TYPE,
       p_firstname out bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE);
      IS
     BEGIN
       SELECT firstname
        into p_firstname
        FROM bb_shopper
        WHERE lastname = p_id;
     EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Last name does not exist');
     END;
    END;
    /
    show errors;
```

The error

```
PACKAGE shop_query_pkg compiled
PACKAGE BODY show_query_pkg compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning
Failed to resolve object details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use the same name and same number of parameters of same type in the overloaded procedure 
and also there the package body name is wrong 
and other little mistakes are there

Additionally the first and second procedure 
the parameter p_firstname types p_firstname out bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE and bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE are both of type Characters(EITHER BOTH CHAR or BOTH VARCHAR2 etc) 
and hence doesn't count as different types

Please use the below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE shop_query_pkg IS
      procedure shop_info(p_id1        IN bb_shopper.idshopper%TYPE,
                  p_firstname1 out bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE);
      procedure shop_info(p_id2        IN bb_shopper.lastname%TYPE,
                  p_firstname2 out bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE);
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY shop_query_pkg IS
    procedure shop_info(p_id1 IN bb_shopper.idshopper%TYPE, 
                                  p_firstname1 out bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE)
               IS
        BEGIN
            SELECT firstname into p_firstname1 FROM bb_shopper WHERE idshopper = p_id1;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
        THEN 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID does not exist');
        END; -- second procedure      
    procedure shop_info(p_id2 IN bb_shopper.lastname%TYPE, 
                                  p_firstname2 out bb_shopper.firstname%TYPE)
               IS
        BEGIN
            SELECT firstname into p_firstname2 FROM bb_shopper WHERE lastname = p_id2;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND 
        THEN 
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Last name does not exist');
        END;
END;
/
show errors;
```

Comment: @atrueresistance
for your first question you can use the view user_errors in the same schema to get all information like line number,position and text

Comment: You can use the same number of parameters and names in overloaded procedure definitions, as long as the type's of at least 1 parameter is different.

Answer (score 0):

Create a package in different schema from APPS and do not create synonym in APPS.

If the package is having some error while compiling, if you are trying to view the error message using 'show error' it will show message as 'Failed to resolve object details' because the package or synonym is not available in APPS schema.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the package spec of the package which you are trying to compile is valid of not. I would suggest you to compile the package spec once again and then compile the package body. This has resolved the issue for me.